# Is it possible to calculate MD5 hash directly in T-SQL language?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, hash, sql-server-2000, md5

I need to hash (MD5) all the password in our Sql Server 2000 database. I can easily generate a C#/VB.NET program to convert (hash) all the passwords, but I was wondering (more for my education than for a real compelling need) if it was possible to calculate MD5 hash directly in T-SQL.
Thanks to anyone who will answer.

Comment: Related, for versions after SQL Server 2000: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3525997/1569

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is using this code, but it is not native to the language.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/xp_md5.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much. I hoped to find a way to do it directly with SQL statements, but this is good too!

Answer (score 7):

In 2005 and later, you can call the [HashBytes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) function.  In 2000, the closest thing is [pwdencrypt/pwdcompare](http://weblogs.asp.net/bradygaster/archive/2003/11/26/39935.aspx), though those functions have their own pitfalls (read the comments of the link).

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind reply. At the end I choose Daniel's answer because I was looking for MD5 hashing, but your one came really close and the suggestion about pwdencryt/pwdcompare made me learn something really interesting.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no native TSQL command to generate MD5 hash's in SQL Server 2000.

In 2005 and above you can use the `HashBytes` function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx

Comment: Even though I chose another answer, I anyway wanted to thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Please see below example/solution using 2008

```
DECLARE @HashThis nvarchar(4000);
SELECT @HashThis = CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),'dslfdkjLK85kldhnv$n000#knf');
SELECT HashBytes('md5', @HashThis);
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing magical about md5, you can implement it as a pure tsql function if you want to. I'm not sure it would be fun in tsql, but there should be nothing preventing you from doing so :)

Answer (score -1):

Just for the record:

```
UPDATE T_WHATEVER_YOUR_TABLE_NAME_IS 
    SET PREFIX_Hash = LOWER(SUBSTRING(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(HashBytes('MD5', LOWER('a-string-with-utf8-encoded-international-text'))), 3, 32) )
```