# Generate MD5 hash string with T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to generate MD5 Hash string of type varchar(32) without using fn_varbintohexstr

```
SUBSTRING(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(HashBytes('MD5', 'email@dot.com')), 3, 32)
```

So it could be used inside a view with SCHEMABINDING

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35200452/compute-md5-hash-of-a-utf8-string/35289890#35289890

Answer (score 249, accepted):

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', 'email@dot.com'), 2)
```

Comment: How do you do this in SQL2005? It's not returning properly encoded string...?

Comment: @JoshuaRountree, see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525997/generate-md5-hash-string-with-t-sql/28903685#28903685

Answer (score 80):

Use [HashBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx)

```
SELECT HashBytes('MD5', 'email@dot.com')
```

That will give you 0xF53BD08920E5D25809DF2563EF9C52B6

-

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(32),HashBytes('MD5', 'email@dot.com'),2)
```

That will give you  F53BD08920E5D25809DF2563EF9C52B6

Comment: @Brendan, you left off the ",2)" at the end.

Comment: @RyanElkins I get the same result as Brendan, and I am certainly included the ",2)" :(

Answer (score 20):

Solution:

```
SUBSTRING(sys.fn_sqlvarbasetostr(HASHBYTES('MD5','your text')),3,32)
```

Answer (score 19):

None of the other answers worked for me. Note that SQL Server will give different results if you pass in a hard-coded string versus feed it from a column in your result set. Below is the magic that worked for me to give a perfect match between SQL Server and MySql

```
select LOWER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', CONVERT(varchar, EmailAddress)), 2)) from ...
```

Comment: Using `LOWER()` is only necessary if it is case sensitive.

Comment: The first conversion turns out to be important. This gives identical `MD5` Hash compared to `MD5()` function of `Postgresql`. I was wonder why the `MD5` hashs differs from `Python` and `Postgresql`. Thanks for the recipe..

Answer (score 18):

For data up to **8000** characters use:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', 'email@dot.com'), 2)
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/34882/0)</kbd>

For binary data (without the limit of 8000 bytes) use:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), master.sys.fn_repl_hash_binary(@binary_data), 2)
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/34883/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
select SUBSTRING(sys.fn_sqlvarbasetostr(HASHBYTES('MD5',  'email@dot.com' )),3,32)
```

Comment: This also works in SQL Server 2005 but only for ascii characters. If I use it with extended characters such as the string 'ødipus' the returned MD5 is wrong. How do I handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONVERT(
      VARCHAR(32),
      HASHBYTES(
                   'MD5',
                   CAST(prescrip.IsExpressExamRX AS VARCHAR(250))
                   + CAST(prescrip.[Description] AS VARCHAR(250))
               ),
      2
  ) MD5_Value;
```

works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't explicitly say you wanted the string to be hex; if you are open to the more space efficient base 64 string encoding, and you are using SQL Server 2016 or later, here's an alternative:

```
select SubString(h, 1, 32) from OpenJson(
    (select HashBytes('MD5', 'email@dot.com') h for json path)
) with (h nvarchar(max));
```

This produces:

```
9TvQiSDl0lgJ3yVj75xStg==
```

Comment: doesn't work "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon."

Comment: @symbiont you have to be in a database with a newer support level; it won't work in an older version or in Master.

Answer (score 1):

Again, most solutions doesn´t work properly, this is carefully tested to return unique results over a cobination of 10 different text columns (KEY CHANGE: convert to varchar(X) where x is the maximum lenght of your string < 4000, for longer strings, use other methods):

```
LOWER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', CONVERT(varchar(4000), EmailAddress)), 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @hash nvarchar(50)
--declare @hash varchar(50)

set @hash = '1111111-2;20190110143334;001'  -- result a5cd84bfc56e245bbf81210f05b7f65f
declare @value varbinary(max);
set @value = convert(varbinary(max),@hash);


select  
 SUBSTRING(sys.fn_sqlvarbasetostr(HASHBYTES('MD5', '1111111-2;20190110143334;001')),3,32) as 'OK'
,SUBSTRING(sys.fn_sqlvarbasetostr(HASHBYTES('MD5', @hash)),3,32) as 'ERROR_01'
,SUBSTRING(sys.fn_sqlvarbasetostr(HASHBYTES('MD5',convert(varbinary(max),@hash))),3,32) as 'ERROR_02'
,SUBSTRING(sys.fn_sqlvarbasetostr(sys.fn_repl_hash_binary(convert(varbinary(max),@hash))),3,32)
,SUBSTRING(sys.fn_sqlvarbasetostr(master.sys.fn_repl_hash_binary(@value)),3,32)
```

Comment: Solution  ... declare @hash varchar(50)  https://md5.gromweb.com/?string=1111111-2%3B20190110143334%3B001