# mssql where md5(tablefield) = md5value?

Tags: php, sql-server, md5

I usually don't work with MSSQL and wonder how i can match a md5 value of a field value stored as string.

In mysql i would use

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE md5(field) = $md5value
```

but i can't find a simple solution for this in mssql.

Now i loop all posts and check for the matched value in the loop, but this is way to slow.

How do I solve this in MSSQL?

I have no possibility to add a extra field in the table and store the md5 value, so i have to do the check this way.

Using odbc driver in php.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525997/generate-md5-hash-string-with-t-sql

Answer (score 1):

MSSQL uses no MD5(), but a function called [HASHBYTES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE HASHBYTES('MD5',field) = $md5value
```

This function appends '0x' to the hash though, so to fully check it, you need:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE HASHBYTES('MD5',field) = '0x' . $md5value
```

Edit: in PHP, it looks like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE HASHBYTES('MD5',field) = \"0x" . $md5value . '"';
```

Comment: This gives me Incorrect syntax near '641' when the given md5value is 641d77dd5271fca28764612a028d9c8e

Comment: @tobros91: what is your SQL string now? I suspect you've just added your MD5 string literal without quotes.

Comment: If i use quotes i get Synax error, and the whole MD5 value.

$sql="SELECT * FROM APPLICATION_DETAIL WHERE HASHBYTES('MD5',APPLICATION_ID) = '0x' . '".$key."'";

Comment: Umm.. i meant the string concatenation within php...   $sql="SELECT * FROM APPLICATION_DETAIL WHERE HASHBYTES('MD5',APPLICATION_ID) = " . '"0x' . $key . '"';

Comment: Edited my post (and my comment above, fixed a typo)

Comment: Thanks for your patience, i tried several combinations with quotes with different errors, latest is "The cursor was not declared" with the latest solution.