# How to store a zip in a sql server 2005 only with sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, binaryfiles

I'm using SQL Server 2005 and I only can use Management Studio (it's a staging/production server). I need to save a zip file from local machine (server) into a blob field.

I do this:

```
create table CFile (id int, thefile varbinary(max))

INSERT INTO CFile
    (id, thefile)
    SELECT 1, 
        BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(
            Bulk 'C:\test.zip', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB
```

and was ok, but then when:

```
SELECT * FROM CFile
```

I saw the row but I can't see the data in thefile field, and is not null (checked also with ISNULL function)

So there is the data but I'cant read it? why? How i retrieve it from Management Studio again, at least as varchar?

I try with

```
INSERT INTO CFile (id, thefile) VALUES (3,cast('asasdfadsfadsfdsafadsfasdfadsfasdfd' as varbinary))
```

and it works, I can see the content of the field.

Any help or tip in this will be preciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure SQL management viewer does not have a BLOB viewer.  You will have to save it back to a file.

You can check with DATALENGTH(thefile) to test if the field was loaded.

Comment: so did u think in any way to verified that the file was suscefully loaded? The only way that I've to check that is management because i don't have really access to the server (it's trought a third-company deployment) Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks Neil N !! Yep, with DATALENGTH() works! U've all right :)

Comment: perhaps there is a way to run a MD5 sum on the server?

Comment: that's an excellent idea, cause also i can check the integrity. I'll try it

Comment: This questions might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910617/is-it-possible-to-calculate-md5-hash-directly-in-t-sql-language